# No description,No repository field,No readme data warning in time of installing Mocha

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am getting this warning at the time of installing mocha in ubuntu

```
npm WARN package.json @ No description
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @ No README data
```

my node version is v0.10.33 and npm version is 1.4.28

I install mocha using :npm install mocha

and also getting error when test a code in node.js

```
ReferenceError: describe is not defined
```

how to resolve this error

Comment: please provide your test code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your package.json doesn't have `description` and `respository` fields nor have a corresponding README file. Add those, and it'll be fine.

Also, as for as getting `ReferenceError`, that's probably because you are running the test using `node`. You should be running as follows:

```
mocha -R spec -u bdd test.js
```

Edited:

You should run based on where you installed `mocha`.

For instance:

```
root/
 tests/test_index.js
 node_modules/mocha
 index.js
```

Then you should do:

```
./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R spec -u bdd tests/test_index.js
```

Comment: @Subham Where did you install mocha? if you did `npm install mocha` without `-g` you have to do `./node/modules/mocha/bin/mocha -R spec -u bdd test.js`

Comment: I installed it inside the test folder

Comment: @Subham I edited the answer. Take a look at it. FYI you shouldn't be installing any modules within a tests folder. they should go under the root folder's node_modules